# Need to allocate variables to an array after using malloc in C

Tags: c

I need to dynamically allocate this array word_count and then return it from the function. However, I can't seem to allocate variables to word_count after I malloc it. It shows an error "expected an expression" I'm new to C programming. There is something I'm doing wrong. What is the right way of allocating these variables to this array? TIA

```
int *word_count = malloc(sizeof(char) * 26);
    if(word_count == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory. Program terminating...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Allocating variables to to word_count */
    word_count = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z};


    return word_count;
```

Comment: You can't use an ***initializer*** after you allocate `word_count`. You will either need to loop assigning each integer value, or use `memcpy`.

Comment: Please quote the error message in full, verbatim, as text and directly here. Make sure to clearly identify the line it refers to (line number is not enough). Consider adding a comment `/* error here */`.

Comment: Do you really need to allocate this "array" dynamically? What is the array used for? What's the use-case? What's the actual problem you need to solve with this code?

Comment: You can do `for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) word_count[i] = i + 'a';` Also, if you are using `word_count` for an actual *word count* -- you want to initialize all to zero.

Comment: And while not portable, you could almost universally rely on the ASCII encoding where `'a'` to `'z'` are encoded contiguously (integers `97` to `122`, inclusive), and perhaps not need this array at all? Then `'a' + index` will be the same as `word_count[index]` with your array.

Comment: Or considering the name *`word_count`*, is this supposed to have counters of letters in a word or string? Then you should initialize the array elements to all zero (but I still don't see any need to allocate it dynamically).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: did you mean to write `word_count[letter-'a']` as a programming trick? What you wrote does not make much sense to me now...

Comment: @virolino Assuming you mean the `word_count[index]` thing, then I really meant that for any valid index `i` then `word_count[i]` would give the same result as `'a' + i` (assuming ASCII encoding or something compatible). For example the index `2` would be the character `'c'` in the array, so `word_count[2] == 'c'`. And `'a' + 2 == 'c'`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: oh, i finally got it. We were applying the trick to different parts of the problem. Hence, the misunderstanding.

Comment: Could you please clarify what those `a, b, c, d,...` are in the posted code? Are they variables of type `int` or did you mean the characters `'a'`, `'b'`, ... ? If those are variables and you known exactly how many of them are needed, why are you dinamically allocating them instead of using a statically sized array? In other words, could you please tell us what's the context of this snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a character between single quotes

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *word_count = malloc(sizeof(char) * 26);
    if(word_count == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory. Program terminating...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Allocating variables to to word_count */
    word_count[0] = 'a';
    word_count[1] = 'b';
    word_count[2] = 'c';
    /*...*/
    return word_count;
}
```

Moreover, you had an integer pointer assigning characters. Either you assign integers to `word_count` or you declare `word_count` as pointer to char type.

You could also assign it like `word_count[0] = a` if you have somewhere defined that `char a = 'a'`.

If you wanna automatize it, you can do it also in a for loop

```
for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
{
    word_count[i] = 'a' + i;
}
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you :)

Comment: How is 'a' a word_count?!?

Comment: Okay my variable naming is terrible. I am not actually counting words here with word_count. a is actually a variable that has a value from another function.

Comment: And how is `a` declared? As `int` type? If so, you will need to declare `word_count` as `int`, as you had it initially, and later assign it like `word_count[0] = a;`. And yes, the naming is a bit confusing :(

Answer (score 1):

The C language does not allow you to assign values to a buffer like that. That notation is reserved to initialize arrays during their declarations.

```
int k[5] = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};  /* will work fine */
```

---

You will need to do something else, e.g.:

```
word_count[0] = a;
word_count[1] = b;
word_count[2] = c;
word_count[3] = d;
....
```

Comment: You want `'a'` and `'b'` (unless `a-z` variables are declared somewhere) -- but we know what you meant.

Comment: I had the same question in my mind, what should be there. I just assumed that they are variables, taken directly from the question. Another question would be: why does `word_count` have exactly 26 positions? Maybe `letter_count`? And if it is `letter_count`, then `'a'`, `'b'` ... do not make sense anyway, they are not counts.

Comment: Yes, it was really wonky -- I did a double take on that in the original question ("What??"). It was also strange to see `int *word_count ..` instead of `char *word_count..` -- but either will work, it's just unclear what the rest of his code is intended to be -- but it looks like he wants to store the ASCII values for `'a' - 'z'` in the array (which if he is using it for a *frequency array* it should just be initialized zero with `calloc`...) Oh well...